# When should a question be closed as a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, duplicate-questions

To be more specific, I have seen people closing questions when they find a duplicate.

The problem is that sometimes these duplicates do not have an accepted answer or working solution.

I understand that an upvoted answer could be credible but is it still fair to close a question in this case?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it absolutely is.  An accepted answer is only the opinion of one person, the person that asked the question.  While that does count for something, and even a little bit more than any other site user, at the end of the day what's truly important is that the community feels that there is an answer that solves the problem, not just the question author, which is why it's entirely appropriate to close a question that has an unaccepted answer with a positive score.

This requirement, if implemented, would only serve to prevent the closure of questions that have no need to be around, would make it harder for people to be directed to the appropriate canonical post on a topic, would encourage users to badger question authors into accepting an answer (to allow for duplicate closures), etc.

Comment: Servy that makes sense, but on the other hand it is possible the solution provided in the duplicate does not solve the OP error

Comment: @meda If that's the case, then the person who marked it as a dup is wrong, and it takes 5 people to close it. There's a significant difference between an unaccepted answer and an answer that doesn't address the question.

Comment: @meda Then they can explain why the proposed duplicate doesn't answer their question, how the questions differ, what problems he has with that answer, etc.  If it becomes apparent that the answer in the duplicate doesn't solve the problem the question can be reopened.

Answer (score 4):

> I understand that an upvoted answer could be credible but is it still fair to close a question in this case?

In a word, yes. If I'm closing as a dup, I've made the decision that in my opinion the other question provides the answer to the current question, and am voting to show I feel that is the case.

In fact, what I'll often do in cases where there's no accepted answer is give the best answer to the original another upvote.