# When is a question different enough to not count as a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

Yesterday I closed [Piping select and using -Property effects multiple commands](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54658439/1630171) as a duplicate of [How to create an Object that outputs a List (Not A Table)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40335091/1630171). My reasoning for the dupe-close was:

- Both questions are essentially asking about PowerShell output formatting, even though the output format they want to achieve is different.
- My answer to the second question covers not just the particular question, but a broader range of PowerShell output formatting issues.
- The specific problem the author of the first question observed is covered in my answer to the second question.

I read [When should a question be closed as a duplicate?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252066/1630171) and also [Tim Post's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254792/1630171) to [When can a question be closed as a duplicate of another?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254697/1630171), but IMO the two questions are not *that* fundamentally different, so I would argue that dupe-hammering should be okay.

However, another user has disagreed with my decision, so I thought I'd take the issue to meta:

Do we consider those two questions similar enough to validate dupe-hammering, and if not, where are we drawing the line?

Comment: Sounds like a separate issue to me. I don't see how the answer on your dupe target addresses PowerShell grouping output format over separate rows outputting the same type, but I might be missing something, I'm not that experienced in PowerShell. Could you explain what part of your answer addresses this issue? The question also could be a lot better by adding expected output and actual output, though, but that doesn't influence the dupe.

Comment: It's addressed after the first code block in my answer, starting at "Beware, however, ..." and ending at the horizontal line after the next 3 code blocks. And yes, the question certainly has a lot of room for improvement, but that's not what my question here is about.

Comment: I've seen that, but that refers back to _outputting several things in a row_ and doesn't note that this behavior can also occur when outputting on separate rows.

Comment: The behavior does not occur when you run one command after another in an interactive PowerShell console. It occurs when you run subsequent commands either from a script or (semicolon-separated) in a PowerShell console.

Comment: Ah, I get your point, it wasn't obvious to me that it's applicable to scripts as well but perhaps should've been, now I get why you consider it a duplicate.

Comment: My understanding is that duplicate is about answer. If a question has an answer on an other question and _all_ the answers on this taget apply and satisfy the question then it's a duplicate of the target.

Comment: i'm the one who questioned the dupe-closing. [*grin*] ///// i disagree - the rationale in my case is that there is no possible way anyone would ever get to the buried answer to the question asked. i've tried a few searches and never got to the question/answer that was supposedly being duped. in my opinion, a dupe _should be findable_ ... and this one is not findable at all - not by me, at least.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey That's not a good argument. One reason we have dupes and leave them around is to help people find good answers on otherwise hard to find questions. Getting marked a dupe is not punishment in any way, and doesn't contribute to rate limits/question bans. You can still upvote the question if you think it's well-researched and helpful as it leads people to an answer to this question.

Comment: @ErikA - you folks are more experienced at this ... but i think you have lost contact with reality on this subject. [*grin*] if it cannot be found with a search, then it aint the answer to the question.

Comment: @Lee That's just not how it works. For example, [it's acceptable to edit an existing answer then close as a duplicate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/363428/7296893). In that case the answer didn't even exist yet. Duplicates are ways of helping the asker and consolidating knowledge for people who search at the same time. There are many similar discussions on meta, consensus is that if the question is somewhat similar and the answer addresses the question, it's a duplicate, and other things (like how easy it is to find) don't matter at all

Comment: i accept that you folks work that way ... but you will never convince me that a question is a dupe of another when the answer to the 1st is buried in one of the answers to the 2nd. there simply is _no freaking way_ anyone could find that buried-in-an-anwer-to-a-different-question info unless they already know it's there. ///// if it's the way y'all work ... OK. but it's actively anti-useful - and it borders on insane. [*frown*]

Comment: @Lee you're free to discuss and bring arguments. You're currently just stating things without substantiating them, and calling others insane. That's not productive and borderline rude.

Comment: @ErikA - understood. i THINK i have posted the idea - un-find-able answers are not answers - but y'all seem to think that is correct. ... ok ...